# How to read and store k, m and data points from text file in python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a text file which contains value of k and m in first line and from second line onward it contains all m dimensional data points like following

```
5 4

1.6 0.3 15.0 14.1

1.3 9.1 0.9 12.4

5.6 9.9 14.4 18.6

25.0 1.3 12.9 2.1

17.2 3.4 9.2 14.7

2.3 2.2 1.2 9.5
.............
```

how to read and store

```
k = 5,

m = 4 and 

x[0] = 1.6, y[0] = 0.3, z[0] = 15.0, t[0] = 14.1 (this could be m dimensional)

x[1] = 1.3, y[1] = 9.1, z[1] = 0.9, t[1] = 12.4 (this could be m dimensional)

x[2] = 5.6, y[2] = 9.9, z[2] = 14.4, t[2] = 18.6 (this could be m dimensional)

........

x[n-1] =  , y[n-1] =  , z[n-1] = , t[n-1] =  (this could be m dimensional)
```

After reading all data points I want to perform farthest first algorithm on it

Comment: It is not clear from your question what part you need help with. Have you already performed step 1: "Learn Python"?

Comment: @usr2564301 No, I am seeking help from the scratch.

Comment: Okay, that makes it much clearer. Stack Overflow is not a suitable site to teach you Python.

Comment: @usr2564301 Yeah I agree and I have tried something like below: Fh = open("fft_datapoints.txt", "r") 
#print(Fh.read()) 

k = 5
m = 4
Data = []

x,y,z,k = [], [], [], []
for l in Fh:
    row = l.split()
    x.append(row[0])
    y.append(row[1])
    z.append(row[2])
    k.append(row[3])      But how can it be generalize to m dimensional space, that is why I asked for help!!

Comment: Then put that code in your question, and add what the problem is *with* that code. I downvoted(!) and close-voted(!!) your question because it is now nothing more than "here, data. Give me code." Hence my first question "do you know Python". I will retract *both* of them if the question gets better.

Comment: @usr2564301 Thank you so much, I am certainly a beginner in Python programming but it seemed to be a bit more complex to me even after trying to resolve it. Thanks for your help once again!!

Comment: Go ahead and [edit] your question into shape. As it is now, it is not suitable for Stack Overflow and may possibly gain more downvotes and closevotes, which can lead to a question limit for you.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need m-dimensional space - you simply need lists.

Create your demodata:

```
data = """5 4

1.6 0.3 15.0 14.1

1.3 9.1 0.9 12.4

5.6 9.9 14.4 18.6

25.0 1.3 12.9 2.1

17.2 3.4 9.2 14.7

2.3 2.2 1.2 9.5"""

fn = "file.txt"

with open(fn, "w") as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Read it back into suitable data structure of lists of lists of floats:

```
fn = "file.txt"
all_data = []
with open(fn,"r") as f:
    k,m = map(float,f.readline().strip().split())
    for line in f:
        if line.strip(): # weed out empties
            line = list(map(float,line.split()))
            all_data.append(line)

print("k:",k,"m:",m)
print(all_data)
```

Gives an output of:

```
k: 5.0 m: 4.0
[[1.6, 0.3, 15.0, 14.1],   # each line is one row of your data
 [1.3, 9.1, 0.9, 12.4],    # its position the same as in your file
 [5.6, 9.9, 14.4, 18.6],   # and you can use those in whatever calculations
 [25.0, 1.3, 12.9, 2.1],   # you need to do 
 [17.2, 3.4, 9.2, 14.7], 
 [2.3, 2.2, 1.2, 9.5]]
```

You have all the numbers in lists and can go from there.

If you need them as `x`,`y`,`z`,`t` you can gather them from `all_data` using [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and leveraging decomposition:

```
x,y,z,t = map(list,zip(*all_data))

print(x)
print(y)
print(z)
print(t)
```

Output:

```
[1.6, 1.3, 5.6, 25.0, 17.2, 2.3]   # x
[0.3, 9.1, 9.9, 1.3, 3.4, 2.2]     # y
[15.0, 0.9, 14.4, 12.9, 9.2, 1.2]  # z
[14.1, 12.4, 18.6, 2.1, 14.7, 9.5] # t
```

Also used: [map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)